# AngularJS bind $scope data to form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a $rootScope variable:

```
$rootScope.register_data = {};
```

I have a view which contains a form:

```
<form name="register_data">
    <div class="popup signup">
        <div class="social">
            <a ng-controller="FacebookCtrl" ng-click="login()" href="javascript:void(0)" class="facebook fb-login-button">Sign up with Facebook</a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="userinfo">
            <div class="left"><input type="text" ng-model="register_data.firstname" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1" required></div>
            <div class="right"><input type="text" ng-model="register_data.email" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex="4" required></div>

            <div class="left"><input type="text" ng-model="register_data.lastname" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2" required></div>
            <div class="right optional"><div class="tip">optional</div><input type="text" ng-model="register_data.dob" tabindex="5" placeholder="DoB (dd/mm/yyyy)"></div>

            <div class="left"><input type="text" ng-model="register_data.phone" placeholder="Phone Number" tabindex="3" required></div>
            <div class="right password"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="picker">&nbsp;</a><input type="password" ng-model="register_data.password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="6" required></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <span class="terms">I agree to the <a href="javascript:void(0)">terms &amp; conditions</a></span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="terms_checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-class="{checked : terms_checked}" ng-click="changeTerms()">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" id="register_btn" ng-click="doRegister(register_data)">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form has a name `register_data` and each field is bound to that via ng-model. It seems to overwrite my `$rootScope.register_data` variable as when I update that none of the form controls update. Though if I remove the form name then it works. However i need the form name to do proper form validation.

Anyone know how I can bind the form controls to a scope object but also keep the form validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the form name to be something else other than the name used as model, since the form controller will be published into related scope, under this name.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more for a n00b to #AngularJS? I am running into this issue currently and would like to know what the best  practice is around this. I have simply referenced them with similar names but think that is going to continue to be a point of confusion till I can fully grasp it.